# How can I decrease the size of system volume information on a drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10

The drive size is 700Gb, it's not C. SVI takes 200gb - 30%. Restore points are disabled on the drive. 
Things that inside the folder:

[image: Content of SVI]

What can I do about it? 200 out of 700 seems way too much even though I don't mind indexing.

Comment: Required reading [About $Recycle.bin, Recycler and System Volume Information Folders in Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/about-recycler-and-system-volume-information-folder-in-xp-and-vista/view-all/)

Comment: It looks like the article suggests I may safely delete the folder because it's not a system drive.

Comment: Correct - it will get recreated though ...

Comment: What you're looking at are Shadow Copies. They're created by System Restore and it will keep doing so unless you disable it for the drive in question.

Comment: @Daniel B I had it disabled long time ago. But the dates are fresh. So my guess is indexing service is at fault.

Comment: It’s not. They are shadow copies. If you don’t believe me, execute `vssadmin list shadows` in an admin command prompt.